# What is the optimal way to parse these strings in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, trading, algorithmic-trading, cryptocurrency

Using Python and given the following *unique* items, what is the optimal way to find the pair that matches the two names combined? For example, how would you find the tuple that corresponds to the string `"BNBBTC"`?

For background, the right index will only ever have ~5 options (of strings length 3 or 4) while the left may have >100.

```
(AMB, BNB),
(AMB, BTC),
(AMB, ETH),
(ARK, BTC),
(ARK, ETH),
(ARN, BTC),
(ARN, ETH),
(AST, BTC),
(AST, ETH),
(BAT, BNB),
(BAT, BTC),
(BAT, ETH),
(BCC, BNB),
(BCC, BTC),
(BCC, ETH),
(BCC, USDT),
(BCPT, BNB),
(BCPT, BTC),
(BCPT, ETH),
(BNB, BTC),
(BNB, ETH),
(BNB, USDT),
(BNT, BTC),
(BNT, ETH),
(BQX, BTC),
(BQX, ETH),
(BTC, USDT),
(BTG, BTC),
```

Comment: why don't you use dictionary, whose key is combined tuple and insert in dictionary.

Comment: Ah that is a very great idea. I believe I will do this.

Comment: looking for the string `'BNBBTCUS'` - could you have `('BNB','BTCUS')` and `('BNBB','TCUS')` as tuples? if so, which one would you use? Are your strings "complete" meaning _all_ letters must be inside the looked up tuple or are you after partial matches - f.e. `'BNBBTCUSDUNNO'`  and either of the tups above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
l = [('AMB', 'BNB'), ('AMB', 'BTC')]

d = dict()

for s in l:
    d[''.join(s)] = s


def find_name(key):
    return d[key] if d.get(key) else None


print(find_name('BNBBTC'))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
l = [('AMB', 'BNB'), ('AMB', 'BTC'),('BNB', 'BTC')]

def find_name(key):
    for Touple in l:
        Flag = 0
        if (''.join(Touple)) == key: 
            Flag = 1
            break

    return Touple if (Flag == 1) else  False

print(find_name('BNBBTC'))
```